# delete 911 address and phone

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to delete a phone number and the 911 address associated with it.  If I disssasiciate the number on one call, then delete the number on a separate call it works.  For some reason when I combine them into a single API call it doesn't work.  I have tried putting sleep statements in between and it is inconsistent, it works a couple of times and then fails.  I have tried to put it into a while loop and same thing, it works a couple of times then fails several times.  When I rerun the same call the second time it works 100% of the time.  It seems like it is caching the disassociate method.  What am I missing to make this work 100% of time?

```
class ProviderTwilio:

    def __init__(self):
        # instantiate env variables
        gen_env = MyEnv()

        # Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        # and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
        account_sid = gen_env.get_key('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
        auth_token = gen_env.get_key('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
        self.client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

def delete_phone_number(self, active_phone_number, customer):

       timeout_min = 1 / 2  # 30 seconds
       timeout_timer = time.time() + 60 * timeout_min

       while True:
           time.sleep(5)
           LOG.info(f"timer is {time.time()}")
           if time.time() > timeout_timer:
               return jsonify({"msg": f"Could not complete task."}), 400
               break

           try:
               # 10 number phone digit
               phone_number = self.get_phone_sid(active_phone_number)
               LOG.info(f"phone number exists")
           except IndexError:
               return jsonify({"msg": f"Phone number provided does not exist"}), 404
               break

           # disassociate phone number
           LOG.info(f"dissociating phone number {phone_number}")
           self.disassociate_ems_address(phone_number)

           # if it disassociates the number correctly then the rest works.

           # If customer has a 911 Address delete it.
           if self.search_ems_address(customer):
               ad_sid = self.search_ems_address(customer)
               try:
                   LOG.info(f"deleting 911 for customer {customer}")
                   self.delete_ems_address(ad_sid)
               except TwilioRestException:
                   continue

           LOG.info(f"deleting phone number {phone_number}")
           self.client.incoming_phone_numbers(phone_number).delete()

           return jsonify({"msg": f"Phone Number {active_phone_number} and 911 address was deleted successfully"}), 200
           break
```

Comment: What are the `disassociate_ems_address` and `delete_ems_address` methods doing? And what is the actual error do you get when this goes wrong?